# How to show an overlay div when hover on a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hover, overlay

I want to show an overlay div sitting on top of the hovered div similar to this effect on IBM website: http://www.ibm.com/us/en/

Please look at the 3 boxes near the footer. Hover on the box "Let's build a smarter planet" to view the effect.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/miljenko/xTZ87/). Basically you need to create 3 divs with a visible and the invisible containers, add *hover* event handler and toggle the *tooltip's* visibility in that handler.

HTML:

```
<div class="parents">
    <div class="box type-1">box 1</div>
    <div class="tooltip type-1">tooltip 1</div>
</div>

<div class="parents">
    <div class="box type-2">box 2</div>
    <div class="tooltip type-2">tooltip 2</div>
</div>

<div class="parents">
    <div class="box type-3">box 3</div>
    <div class="tooltip type-3">tooltip 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parents
{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.box,
.tooltip
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;

    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    text-align: center;
}

.tooltip
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function ()
    {
        // add hover event handler
        $('.box').hover
        (
            function ()
            {
                // find the triggering box parent, and it's tooltip child
                $(this).parent().children('.tooltip').animate
                (
                    {
                        opacity: "toggle",      // toggle opacity
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know about toggle in animate :) Also very nice and clean code!

Comment: Thanks, I find this to be more readable than the usual jQuery formatting.

Comment: The tooltip box doesn't sit on top of the box though

Comment: That's just a matter of styling or style fine-tuning, this shows and you the logic required to make this sort of behavior. I wanted to make it as simple as possible, so more people can understand it. After you figure it out, style it as you wish...

Answer (score 3):

IBM is using Dojo's .expand method. You can do the same functionality in jQuery using the [expand](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/expand) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that. The steps should follow:

**1)** Have 3 blocks like DIVs or UL LIs and add the hidden container inside(or it doesn't matter if you will set the position with jQuery.
If your structure would be:

```
<div class="block">
<div class="invisible"></div>
<div class="visible"></div>
</div>
```

**2)** Attach mouseenter and mouseleave events to all 3 blocks like:

```
$('.block').mouseenter(function() {
// some code to show the hidden container

$(this).find('.visible').show().addClass('visible_container');

});

$('.block').mouseleave(function() {
// some other code to hide the shown container
$('.visible_container').hide(); // Hide all the instances of .visible_container
});
```

**3)** You should modify JS or CSS according to the position methods for your elements so when `show()` is called the element would be displayed right on top of the element. For example if you hidden block would have a CSS rule `position: absolute` you would use:

```
$(this).find('.visible')
       .show()
       .addClass('visible_container')
       .css('top', $(this).offset().top+'px')
       .css('left', $(this).offset().left+'px');
```

In this case the shown container would be adjusted to the right upper corner of the hovered block.

As the hidden container is a child of the block container - no mouseleave event would be called so it would stay nicely displayed.