# How to expand content

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed `div` at the bottom of the page.

Inside the `div` is a `ul`, which can be hovered over to reveal more content (sort of a push up than a dropdown list).

What I want to do is to show the hidden content on hover for each of the hover elements in exactly the same place above the list.

What I also need to do is expand the fixed parent `div`. It has no height so expands with the content but in positioning the content as per above I use `position:absolute` so it breaks out of the parent container and doesn't expand it.

I'm sure this is easier using a click method, but it needs to work on hover too.

Comment: Can you show some code please, perhaps even a jsfiddle example

Comment: jQuery will definitely remedy this. Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884674/how-to-show-an-overlay-div-when-hover-on-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: @Ben - I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e3jkN/9/. This just shows the structure but I need to achieve 2 things in addition to what I have. 1) The .hidden element needs to be in the same position for each hover element, and 2 the parent needs to expand.

Comment: New jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e3jkN/11/

Comment: jquery is fine - will use it to make things a little slicker, but I need it to also work without javascript.